# How can i auto download generated csv file in php?

Tags: php, ajax, csv

I have seen many examples but none of them is resolving my issue.
I generated cvs file in ajax post request ( I am not changing window.location.href). I want this file to auto download just like what happens after changing window.location.href. Currently i don't know solution.Kindly help me here is my code

```
$file_name="temp_".time().".csv";
$new_csv = fopen($file_name, 'w');
fputcsv($new_csv, $csv_data);
fclose($new_csv);
header("Content-type: application/csv; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename =\"" .$file_name. "\"");
readfile($file_name);
unlink($file_name);
exit;
$this->setLayout(false);
return sfView::NONE;
```

Comment: this is NOT possible via ajax. but have a look at answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: can you post your javascript code, if you're not redirecting this is were this would happen.

Comment: Basically i have a very long data array which i can't send in url so thats why i am using post request. But if you know to access data after changing window.location then kindly let me know.thanks

Comment: $.post("<?php echo url_for('admin/ExportQRCSV') ?>/d/" + d.getTime(), postdata.serialize(), function(){
                                $("#loading").hide();
                                $("#loading-overlay").hide();

Comment: here is javascript